# Drupal: Enable search form globally?

Tags: php, drupal

My search component block has the default settings but for an anonymous user it shows a login area instead of the search component and only until you've logged in do you see it.

"Show on every page except the listed pages" and no pages listed..

"Show block for specific roles" - unchecked so all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure anonymous users have the search content permission ticked in admin/user/permissions